# mysqldump, all data including users and permissions

Tags: windows, mysql

I'd like to update my mysql server to the latest version.
To do this I am trying to use mysqldump.  I want to include all databases, all users and all permissions of those users.
Basically an entire backup and restore but to a newer MySQL version (MySQL under Windows, version 5.1.41 to 5.6.x)

Something like this seems to dump all databases:
mysqldump -h host -u root -pmypassword --add-drop-database --routines --all-databases > all-dbs.sql
(note I need isam and innodb databases)

But when I load the resulting script using MySQL Workbench, Data Import, it doesn't appear to restore the Users at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the dumped SQL file contain the `mysql` DB?  Are you certain that root user has access to the mysql tables?

Comment: It doesn't!  Not sure why, any idea?

Comment: Check what privileges this user/host has to the `mysql` database.